# Get all ancestors of a child in postgres recursive query

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am trying to get all related ancestors of a child with more info by joining with another table.
I'm kind of new to backend so recursive cte is hard to understand.

Find SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a9ce3/2)

Data I have : product_id,user_id

Data I need :

| user_id | master_id | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id(john_snow) | null | 4 |
| id(bran_stark) | id(john_snow) | 6 |
| id(arya_stark) | id(bran_stark) | 8 |
| id(sansa_stark) | id(arya_stark) | 10 |

So that I can add profits to respective users and least cost as company profit.

Comment: Please provide the create table and insert statements for this data sample (preferably in a fiddle). Never post data as image.

Comment: @JimJones Question updated with fiddle

Comment: You may find closure tables easier to use and query - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701519/5962802

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RECURSIVE` CTE is what you're looking for. It might look confusing at the first glance, but after a little practice it becomes self-explanatory. In the end, it is just a `UNION` with two slightly different queries:

```
WITH RECURSIVE get_ancestor(child,parent,cost) AS (
  SELECT r.user_id,r.parent_id,c.cost FROM user_relation r
  JOIN product_cost c ON c.user_id = r.user_id
  UNION 
  SELECT g.child,g.parent,c.cost FROM get_ancestor g
  JOIN user_relation r ON r.user_id = g.child
  JOIN product_cost c ON c.user_id = r.user_id 
)
SELECT * FROM get_ancestor;
```

Demo: [`SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a9ce3/3)