# PostgreSQL ltree: Get all entries and the ancestors in ltree from another table

Tags: java, postgresql, ltree

##### Tree table

| node_Id | tree_path::ltree |
| --- | --- |
| aaaa | aaaa |
| bbbb | aaaa . bbbb |
| cccc | aaaa . bbbb . cccc |
| dddd | aaaa . bbbb . dddd |
| eeee | eeee |
| ffff | eeee . ffff |

##### Object table

| object_id | node_id_fk | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | aaaa | name1 | node |
| 2222 | aaaa | name2 | node |
| 3333 | cccc | name3 | node |
| 4444 | dddd | name4 | node |
| 5555 | eeee | name4 | node |
| 6666 | eeee | name6 | node |
| 7777 | bbbb | name7 | node |
| 8888 | dddd | name8 | node |
| 9999 | dddd | name9 | node |

#### What I want to achieve in two steps:

1. Get all entries from the "Object table" for requested node_ids and all ancestor ids in the tree_path in the "Tree table".
2. And then add a column  `requested_node_id`  to to response from (1) to show the **requested** node_id to the  "Object table" entries.

For the **1. step**, i think,  the the query looks something like that

Only the duplicate entries are not shown.

So we get these entries for the requested nodeIds `('bbbb', 'dddd')` from the "Object table"

| object_id | node_id_fk | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | aaaa | name1 | node |
| 2222 | aaaa | name2 | node |
| 7777 | bbbb | name7 | node |
| 1111 | aaaa | name1 | node |
| 2222 | aaaa | name2 | node |
| 4444 | dddd | name4 | node |
| 7777 | bbbb | name7 | node |
| 8888 | dddd | name8 | node |
| 9999 | dddd | name9 | node |

For the **2. step** (show column with the requested node_Id) I don't know how the query :(
the response should look like this:

| object_id | node_id_fk | name | type | requested_node_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | aaaa | name1 | node | bbbb |
| 2222 | aaaa | name2 | node | bbbb |
| 7777 | bbbb | name7 | node | bbbb |
| 1111 | aaaa | name1 | node | dddd |
| 2222 | aaaa | name2 | node | dddd |
| 4444 | dddd | name4 | node | dddd |
| 7777 | bbbb | name7 | node | dddd |
| 8888 | dddd | name8 | node | dddd |
| 9999 | dddd | name9 | node | dddd |

Unfortunately only shows the node_id from the "node table" and not the **requested** node id

I hope the question is clear, leet me know if not

Comment: Are you forced to go through step 1 or is step 2 just what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also double check your values for the Tree table. It looks like there are some issues with original data.

Comment: Hi @lemon, its just **step 2** what I want as a result. 
Regarding the "tree_path" values of the tree table, they are combined with a period `aaaa.bbbb.cccc`, but the stackoverflow editor doesn't let me save it that way

Comment: I see `aaa` and `aaaa`, `dddd` and `ddddd` as two distinct values for each couple, was that intended? I see duplicate records in step 1 output, was that intended too?

Comment: The recursive fetch portion of your question (step 1) can be solved with this technique : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68317916/get-all-ancestors-of-a-child-in-postgres-recursive-query

Comment: @lemon the `aaa` and `ddddd` should be the `aaaa` & `dddd`. My fault.
For the output I would also like to have the duplicate entries